# Can you run different domain names on the same Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby, comfortable-mexican-sofa

The Comfy CMS [says](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Sites) that you can run several sites off of a single installation with separate hostnames, such as, `en.example.com` and `fr.example.com`. But I'm wondering if you can run several different sites with different hostnames like, `example1.com` and `example2.com`?

Comment: Oh, good Lord, it really is called Comfortable Mexican Sofa.  Where are the PC Police when you need them?

Comment: 'Comfortable Mexican Sofa' - Interesting ;)

Comment: I believe the relevent code is [here](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/app/controllers/comfy/cms/base_controller.rb)

Comment: I have a theory that some developers name projects specifically to create legitimate SO questions with bizarre-sounding titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and ran an install of Comfy on DigitalOcean and tried it out with two different domain names. It worked just fine. Comfortable Mexican Sofa has the capabilities to run multisites with different domain names on one Comfy install.